# Detect when a shape is created or modified in a range and copy it into other multiple ranges

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I posted this in the Stack overflow in Spanish site but since it is not having any views at all I'll post it here.

The thing I have is multiple ranges of cells, that update with the same content whenever I update the main primary range so I have multiple copies of one thing.
The only thing that copies over is content and all formats but I can fire the action only when any of the cells in that primary range updates.
However I want to be able to put images, text boxes and shapes in that range and have them copied over to the rest of the ranges as well, also modifying the rest of the shapes in the ranges when I update the first one.

It seems a hard task to do mainly because:

- It seems it is not possible to position shapes etc in a relative way to the range the shape object is in.

- I'd have to predefine names for those objects to be created.

- Everytime I create a new shape the new name generates with a number higher to the latest shape created before it, even If I delete it, the next new one created will be created with a higher number continueing the chain. So it seems the stack of numbers won't reset. I want them to be alsways created starting from 1 to 10.
- The hardest, is that there seems not to be a possible way of detecting when a shape was pasted, created or modified in general nor inside a specific range.

How could you achieve this when Excel has no events for images, objects or text box items and is not oriented towards paper design automation?

Comment: You might get more interest in your question if you post your existing code.  Since you're creating new shapes, you have control over their names: you just need a consistent naming scheme that allows you to link all the "copies" to the original items in your primary range.

Comment: "It seems it is not possible to position shapes etc in a relative way to the range the shape object is in" - most (all?) shapes types have a `TopLeftCell` property, and you can always determine any shape's position relative to any cell by comparing the shape and the cell's `Top` and `Left` properties.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'll have to try it then.